# Composition with an exact functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Suppose $F:C\longrightarrow D$ is exact and that $G:D\longrightarrow E$ is another functor such that $GF$ is exact. Is $G$ necessarily exact? Counter examples?

Comment: I think the question as currently stated is no for obvious reason that $GF$ do not care about the behavior of $G$ outside of the image of $F$. The example Fernando Muro gave below also shows this, as $G$ is exact on the image of $C$. It would be more interesting to seek for a counterexample where $F$ is essentially surjective.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, you are right to point that out.
Any suggestion for the counter example in this case?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest counterexample is $F=0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $C$ be the category of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces and $D=E$ the category of abelian groups. Take $F$ to be the forgetful functor, which is fully faithful and exact, and $G=-\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2$. The latter is not exact but the composite $GF=0$ is the trivial functor, which is exact.